# How to unsplit a window in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do you unsplit multiple windows and arrange them side by side in a single screen in SQL Developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you split. If it's two separate files that are now separated into two windows:

1. Right click on the tab of the window you want to unsplit.
2. Click "Collapse Document Tab Group" at the bottom of the context menu.

It will place it so that it's in the same screen as the existing content with a tab.

If you split the contents of one window into multiple views:

1. Right click on the tab of the window you want to unsplit.
2. Select "Unsplit" near the bottom of the context menu.